# Let $E/\Bbb{Q}:y^2=x^3＋x$ has CM over $ \Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{-1})$. How can I prove a reduction of isogeny $[1＋2\sqrt{-1}]$ is inseparable?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, complex-multiplication

Let $E/\Bbb{Q}:y^2=x^3＋x$ has CM by $ \Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{-1})$.
How can I prove a reduction of isogeny $[1＋2\sqrt{-1}] \pmod{(1＋2\sqrt{-1}}$) is inseparable ?

I know one way to judge this. Examing invariant differential with the theory of complex multiplication gives this is purely inseparable and reduction at $\pmod{5}$ to $5$-th Frobenius.

But maybe there are easy way to prove this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please avoid such poorly phrased questions. $E/\Bbb{Q}$ has CM by $\Bbb{Z}[i]$, it doesn't make sense to say "CM over $\Bbb{Q}(i)$". The endomorphism $1+2i\in End(E)$ is of course separable. What is maybe inseparable is $1+2i\in End(C)$ where $C/\Bbb{F}_5:y^2=x^3+x$.

Comment: @reuns I think the first sentence makes perfect sense:  the CM endomorphism $(x, y) \mapsto (-x, iy)$ is defined not over $\mathbb Q$, but only over $\mathbb Q(i)$.

Comment: @reuns I think your first argument does not work. $E/ \overline{ \Bbb{F}_5}$ is ordinary, so $[5]$ is separable so $[5]=[1＋2i][1-2i]$ is separable makes no contradiction, although your argument works in the case of supersingular.

Comment: $[p]$ is never separable for elliptic curves over $\overline{\Bbb{F}}_p$, it is always $[p]=\phi^*\phi_p$ the Frobenius times its dual isogeny.

Comment: You can’t say whether $[1+2i]$ is or not inseparable over $\mathbb{F}_5$ unless you’ve decided what $i\in \mathbb{F}_5$ is: is it $2$ or $3$ (ie is the CM endomorphism “$i$” $(x,y) \longmapsto (-x,2y)$ or $(x,y) \longmapsto (-x,3y)$)? Indeed, as $E$ is ordinary, exactly one of $1-2i$ and $1+2i$ is separable mod $5$.

Comment: Sorry, but in this situation, $ \tilde {[1＋2i]}$ 's '$i$' is an element of $ \Bbb{Z}[i]$, not an element of $ \Bbb{F}_5$. Here, $ \tilde$ means reduction by prime ideal $(1＋2i)$.

Comment: $i$ corresponds to $2$ by the isormorphism $ \Bbb{Z}[ i]/(1＋2i)\cong \Bbb{F_5}$, So I think there is no need to decide what $i$ is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let $f$ be a non constant map of curves. Then $f$ is
> separable if and only if the map of pull back of differential form
> $ω_E$, $ \ f*$ is nonzero.

Let $\tilde E$ be a reduction mod $(1＋2\sqrt{-1})$,$E$ has good reduction at this prime ideal.

$ \tilde{[1+2\sqrt{-1}]}^*\tilde ω_E= \tilde {(1＋2\sqrt{-1})} \tilde {ω_E}=(1+2・2)   \tilde ω_E=5\tilde ω_E=0$ implies
$\tilde{[1+2\sqrt{-1}]}$is inseparable(Especially, degree of morphism is $5$, the map is purely inseparable).